# How to automate recompiling with custom patches for repository sources when updates are available?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dnf, patch

I have some patches that I want to apply to various software that I run which add customization that is unlikely to be accepted or has been rejected upstream.

I can already download the source for these packages from my distribution's repository and rebuild them into an RPM with changes that will replace the available binary release. But subsequent updates will still override my RPM as new updates and security fixes appear. I don't want to change this as I also want these updates as they arrive to keep my system secure. But this also requires that I pay special attention to updates as they replace my own altered packages.

Is there anything that I can do so that when an update becomes available, to instead automate downloading the latest source and build it with my patches applied? This would be alternative to downloading and installing the new binary. Ideally, I would want this to occur automatically when I perform an update through YUM/dnf, with any problem being reported there as a failed build.

I am running Fedora.